# MongoDB does not return a field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

It must be a silly mistake but I can't find it.
When I run `db.getCollection('communes').findOne({})`, 
I obtain:

`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b851a19db72301ae771c57"),
    "﻿COMMUNE" : "ALAA6",
    "LIBGEO" : "ROHRBACH",
    "PAYS" : "Allemagne"
}`

which is fine.

But when I run `db.getCollection('communes').findOne({COMMUNE: "ALAA6"})`, it returns nothing!

For strange reasons, filtering on other fields work, so when I run `db.getCollection('communes').findOne({LIBGEO: "ROHRBACH"})`, it returns the result. Same thing filtering on `"PAYS"`.

Adding quotes around `COMMUNE`, i.e. running `db.getCollection('communes').findOne({"COMMUNE": "ALAA6"})` or using `find` instead of `findOne` doesn't change anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my fault. The collection has been created from an Excel export, and it seems the first column contains a strange character. Querying from the Robo3T client did not show it, but querying from Python returns:

`{'LIBGEO': 'ROHRBACH',
 'PAYS': 'Allemagne',
 '_id': ObjectId('59b851a19db72301ae771c57'),
 '\ufeffCOMMUNE': 'ALAA6'}`

so obviously the `\ufeff`char before `COMMUNE`should be removed...